# Need UserVoice feedback page functionality

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I like the feedback link that's static while the page scrolls and I want to add something similar to my site. See www.bind.pt, right side, for example. However I don't want to use UserVoice. I want to use a popup window with a form-to-email functionality.

Is there a similar sample asp.net component or Javascript that's available for a lazy developer like me for re-use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-position-menu-like-slashdots-comment-filtration-menu) - the poster's own answer.

Enjoy!